# Prove that every row has a single $1$ or a single $-1$ or one of each $\Rightarrow$ $\det A = 1$ or $-1$ or $0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am solving the problem of linear algebra textbook.

The problem is

> If every row of $A$ has either a single $+1$, or a single $-1$, or one
>   of each (and is otherwise zero), show that $\det A = 1$ or $-1$ or
>   $0$.

---

I proved it using induction only when every row has single $1$ or $-1$ case like the following:

1. I first showed that always a determinant is $1$ or $-1$ or $0$ for any $2$ by $2$ matrices.
2. I supposed that a determinant of $k$ by $k$ matrix is $1$ or $-1$ or $0$.
3. I proved that it holds for $k+1$ by $k+1$ matrix.

---

However!!, I failed to prove that one of each case.... please someone let me know how to prove it. thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the antecedent is (is it about square matrices) and what exactly you failed to proove?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume we are dealing with square matrices here. The proof will be inductive.

For $1\times1$ matrices, it is trivial. Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and suppose that the statement holds for $n\times n$ matrices. Let $A$ be a $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix. There are two possibilities:

1. There is a row with a single $1$ or a single $-1$. Then we use Laplace expansion along that row and we use the induction hypothesis, unless we get a matrix with a row of zeros, whose determinant is $0$.
2. Otherwise, every row has one and only one $1$, one and only one $-1$ and all other entries are $0$. Then every row belongs to the space $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n+1}=0$ and therefore the determinant is $0$, because the rows are linearly dependent.

Comment: I don't get the downvote; this seems perfectly OK.

Comment: C'm on @Jim, only one term in the expansion with a cofactor that satisfies the induction hypothesis.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thank you. I also don't get it.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: Your solution is fine (+1).

Comment: @quasi I was corrrecting that already. Thanks.

Comment: @quasi Again, thanks. What I did was to replace $x_n$ with $x_{n+1}$.

Comment: It is not valid to start with $n=1$, since that case cannot have 2 entries on the same row, which is essential here. It should start with $n=2$, which admittedly is still trivial.

Comment: @Paul I don't agree. The assertion “every row of A has either a single $+1$, or a single $−1$, or one of each” makes sense for $1\times1$ matrices.

Comment: The assertion makes sense, but not the deduction structure

Comment: @Paul If I assume that the statement holds for $1\times1$ matrices and if the assumptions are valid for a $2\times2$ matrix $A$, then either there is one entry of $A$ which is equal to $0$ or there is not. If there is, I can apply the induction hypothesis. Otherwise, the sum of the entries of each row is $0$, which implies that the rows are linearly dependent, which implies that the determinant is $0$. What's the passage in this argument that doesn't make sense?

Comment: Can you explain 'the rows are linearly dependent in (2) statement' in a bit more detail?

Comment: @Danny_Kim Sure. You have $n+1$ rows. And they all belong to the $n$-dimensional space$$\bigl\{(x_1.x_2,\ldots,x_{n+1})\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\,|\,x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n+1}=0\bigr\}.$$When you have more than $n$ vectors in a $n$-dimensional space, they are always linearly dependent.

Comment: Is the space, $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots x_{n+1} = 0$, $n$-dimensional?

Comment: @Danny_Kim Yes. One basis with $n$ elements is$$\bigl\{(1,-1,0,0,\ldots,0,0),(0,1,-1,0,\ldots,0,0),(0,0,1,-1,\ldots,0,0),\ldots,(0,0,0,0,\ldots,1,-1)\bigr\}.$$

Comment: Fair enough.  I withdraw my objection.

Answer (score 0):

Define a graph on $2n$ points, representing the rows and columns of the matrix, with an edge for every nonzero entry. By assumption the vertex degrees in the graph are at most$~2$, so the connected components of the graph are either paths or cycles. Moreover each component "occupies" a certain set of rows and columns; by permutation of rows and columns of the matrix we can make those sets be consecutive, and have the matrix in block form; it suffices to show that each square block has determinant in $\{-1,0,1\}$ (and the presence of any non-square block makes the global determinant $0$).

In the case of a "path" connected component, which must have an odd number of edges in order to correspond to a square block, the first edge can be made to kill the second edge by a row or column operation, then the third kills the forth, and so forth so that the only such components that remain are isolated edges; such edges represent a determinant value of $+1$ or $-1$.

In the case of a "cycle" component, all the columns it occupies have sum $1+-1=0$, and this forces them to be linearly dependent (the subspace of zero-sum columns is proper): the determinant is$~0$.